# I don't think I understand Os.walk fully

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to build a program for work that deletes unneeded files generated by a software when we export stills.

I was quite happy with how it's working. You just drop a folder that you want and it will delete all the files in that folder. But my boss saw me using it and asked if he could just drop the top directory folder in and it would go into each folder and delete the DRX to save him time of doing it manually for each folder.

This is my current program -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import site
import threading
import time
from os import path 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


while True:
    backboot = 'n'
    while backboot == 'n':

        print ("")
        file = (input("Please drag and drop the folder containing DRX files you wish to delete : "))
        path = file[:-1]
        os.chdir(path)
        drx = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".drx")]
        amount = (str(len(drx)))

        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
        print ('I have found ' + amount + ' files with the .drx extension and these will now be deleted')
        print("")
        print("")
        print(*drx,sep='\n')
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
        exts = ('.drx')


        for item in drx:
                if item.endswith(".drx"):
                    os.remove(item)

        print ('Deleted ' + amount + ' files.')
        print('')
```

What I understand about `OS.walk` it's generating the `trees` or folders in a given directory by going up or down the tree. So far, I have the user's input for a path location -

```
file = (input("Please drag and drop the folder containing DRX files you wish to delete : "))
        path = file[:-1]
        os.chdir(path
```

I then scan that directory for `DRX files`

```
drx = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".drx")]
```

and turn that into a string as well in order to tell the user how many files I found.

```
amount = (str(len(drx)))
```

So, I'm guessing, would I need to implement the OS.walk before or during the DRX scan? Would this be better done whit a function? I'm just trying to wrap my head around `OS.walk` so any help would be amazing. :)

I guess, I'm quite stuck on how to get `OS.walk` to read my path variable.

```
for root, dirs, items in os.walk(path):
```

Comment: BTW avoid doing `os.chdir`. You don't need that with `os.walk`. `os.walk` yields `root` (the directory) and a list of `files` (names) and `dirs`. You can rely on `root` being coherent with `files` and `dirs` names. use `os.path.join` to generate the full file/dir path

Comment: is your question about: "how to find and delete files with `*.drx` pattern in a dirtree" ?

Comment: Try Pathlib if python version above or equal to 3.4,  [x.unlink() for x in Pathlib.Path(dir_path).glob('*.drx')] work for you

Answer (score 0):

`root` is the absolute path for your `path` input, `dirs` and `items` are lists which contain every dir' and file's relative path to the `root` inside `root`.

```
for root, dirs, items in os.walk(path):
    for file in filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".drx"), items):
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        #do what you like to do
```